# Failed to load jpg images from android camera

Tags: android, camera

After connecting my Android camera, and using File Manager to navigate to the image directory, then when clicking on a jpg icon I get the error popup saying:

```
Could not load image '20150813_160509.jpg'.
Failed to open input stream for file"
```

Camera is Samsung Android. Directory tree is DCIM>Camera>, where the images are.

I then tried Shotwell and get:
42 photos failed to import due to a file or hardware error:

```
/run/user/1000/gvfs/mtp:host=%5Busb%3A002%2C002%5D/Phone/DCIM/Camera/20150314_160836.jpg
/run/user/1000/gvfs/mtp:host=%5Busb%3A002%2C002%5D/Phone/DCIM/Camera/20150318_182204.jpg
/run/user/1000/gvfs/mtp:host=%5Busb%3A002%2C002%5D/Phone/DCIM/Camera/20150319_180953.jpg
/run/user/1000/gvfs/mtp:host=%5Busb%3A002%2C002%5D/Phone/DCIM/Camera/20150319_181219.jpg
(and 38 more)
```

Comment: If the device is mounted via MTP you probably need to copy the files over first. Also, using a photo viewer not a photo "manager" app may work